# Python text-to-speech in a separate thread

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, text-to-speech, pyttsx3

I have a Python program in which I would like to have a voice report certain events, but I don't want to pause the main loop of my program while the voice speaks. I thought I could achieve this by running pyttsx3 in a separate thread (as shown below), but it is not working. The whole program pauses as the voice reads. Are there any workarounds or better solutions for this?

```
import pyttsx3
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def text_to_speech(engine, txt):
    print(f"Speaking: {txt}")
    engine.say(txt)
    engine.runAndWait()

engine = pyttsx3.init()

for n in range(1,21):
    sleep(.1)
    if n % 5 == 0:
        txt = f'{n} is divisible by 5.'
        Thread(target=text_to_speech(engine, txt)).start()
    else:
        print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

The top answer found in this post was helpful in resolving this problem: [Running pyttsx3 inside a game loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63892455/running-pyttsx3-inside-a-game-loop)

It works well, but so far, I have yet to figure out how to interrupt the speaking, so it is not perfect.